# What happens at webserver when a browser is closed or refreshed in between a request?

Tags: http, webserver

You make a request to an asp.net mvc web page. Before the webserver is able to respond, suppose you either close the browser or refresh the page. Does the web server still continue processing the original request and then discard the results at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the browser is closed, the TCP connection will be closed as well. The web server eventually receives some sort of EOF. Until this happens, the web server will process the request as usual.